# relevant code for ngClass.xs or md in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm porting an angular app to reactjs. almost work done but stuck at one point.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="no-js one-page-layout sound-effects"
     [ngClass]="{'is-card-loaded loaded is-card-open is-card-opened':isCardOpen,
     'is-ajax-page-active is-ajax-page-loaded': isSectionOpen}"
     [ngClass.xs]="{'is-card-loaded loaded is-card-open is-card-opened':true,
     'is-ajax-page-active is-ajax-page-loaded': isSectionOpen}"
     [ngClass.md]="{'is-card-loaded loaded is-card-open is-card-opened':true,
     'is-ajax-page-active is-ajax-page-loaded': isSectionOpen}">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

[ngClass.xs] available in angular flexlayout https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/ngClass-API

In the above code, if the screen is small or medium, then the following classes are added by default `is-card-loaded loaded is-card-open is-card-opened` but I couldn't find a relevant code in reactjs. My question is, Is there any way to add those classes by default when the screen is small or medium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not supported natively. There are two solutions you are looking for. The first is, conditionally setting classes. The second is, accessing media query information to use in said conditional classes.

The first solution is easy. There is a great library called [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) that handles conditionally setting style classes.

The second solution can be a bit of pain depending on whether or not you are using React Hooks. Hooks seem to have better options for simply access the current device (sm, md, lg) but then again you could probably write your own solution in less than 50 lines. Here are several popular options you can look through that are React specific but you could also start looking for a Vanilla JS Media Query solution.

- [react-responsive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive)
- [react-socks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-socks)
- [react-media](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-media)

React version (using react-socks Hooks):

```
// I like to import it as cx for brevity
const cx = require('classnames');

// Inside render function
const breakpoint = useCurrentBreakpointName();
const breakpointClasses = {
  md: 'classes-for-md',
  sm: 'classes-for-sm'
};

const classes = cx(
  'no-js one-page-layout sound-effects',
  breakpointClasses[breakpoint], // undefined is ignored
  {
    'is-card-loaded loaded is-card-open is-card-opened': isCardOpen
    'is-ajax-page-active is-ajax-page-loaded': isSectionOpen,
  }
);

return (
  <div className={classes} />
);
```

React version (using react-responsive Hooks)

```
// I like to import it as cx for brevity
const cx = require('classnames');

// I'd hide these behind utility functions so as not to duplicate the query
// in every component.
const isMD = useMediaQuery({ query: '(min-device-width: 1200px)' });
const isSM = useMediaQuery({ query: '(min-device-width: 800px)' });

const classes = cx(
  'no-js one-page-layout sound-effects',
  {
    'is-card-loaded loaded is-card-open is-card-opened': isCardOpen
    'is-ajax-page-active is-ajax-page-loaded': isSectionOpen,
    'classes-for-md': isMD,
    'classes-for-sm': isSM
  }
);

return (
  <div className={classes} />
);
```

React example (using Render Children)

```
// I like to import it as cx for brevity
const cx = require('classnames');

return (
  <Media queries={{
    small: "(max-width: 599px)",
    medium: "(min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 1199px)",
    large: "(min-width: 1200px)"
  }}>
    {matches => (
      <div className={cx(
        'no-js one-page-layout sound-effects',
        {
          'is-card-loaded loaded is-card-open is-card-opened': isCardOpen
          'is-ajax-page-active is-ajax-page-loaded': isSectionOpen,
          'classes-for-md': matches.medium,
          'classes-for-sm': matches.small
        }
      )}>
        <Fragment>
          {matches.small && <p>I am small!</p>}
          {matches.medium && <p>I am medium!</p>}
          {matches.large && <p>I am large!</p>}
        </Fragment>
      </div>
    )}
  </Media>
);
```

So as you can see, lots of solutions depending on how you want to write your React components. Neither is supported natively. React is very barebones, sort of like BackboneJS or EmberJS from back in the day. It keeps it lean and really powerful but you also end up relying on dozens of libraries so that you don't recreate the wheel. Hopefully you find what you need in the libraries I've linked.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR No

Angular being a framework has a lot of things built inside, React is just a library that allows you to handle the user interface but it doesn’t care about what you use to build it, the good thing is that you can plug another libraries to make it work according to your needs.

Talking about adding classes depending on the screen size, there are some libraries you can use like bootstrap or material-ui or you can build it on your own using hooks to attach an event listener to the window to detect the size of the screen and using something like classnames to apply the classes.

Maybe this can help you https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-hook/window-size
https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames